# Two Postgres tables with same column name and same Index name. Need to drop index on one of them

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I have two tables:

```
x_development=# \d+ xref__email_addresses__organizations
                              Table "public.xref__email_addresses__organizations"
         Column          |            Type             |       Modifiers        | Storage | Stats target | Description 
-------------------------+-----------------------------+------------------------+---------+--------------+-------------
 email_address_id        | integer                     | not null               | plain   |              | 
 rorganization_id        | integer                     | not null               | plain   |              | 
 last_update             | timestamp without time zone | not null default now() | plain   |              | 
Indexes:
    "email_address_id_idx" UNIQUE, btree (email_address_id)
    "xref_idx" UNIQUE, btree (email_address_id, organization_id)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "email_address_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (email_address_id) REFERENCES email_addresses(email_address_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
    "organization_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (realtor_organization_id) REFERENCES realtor_organizations(realtor_organization_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT


x_development=# \d+ email_addresses
                                                          Table "public.email_addresses"
       Column       |  Type   |                                 Modifiers                                  | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
--------------------+---------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 email_address_id   | integer | not null default nextval('email_addresses_email_address_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 email_address      | citext  | not null                                                                   | extended |              | 
 unsubscribe_reason | text    | not null default ''::text                                                  | extended |              | 
Indexes:
    "email_addresses_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (email_address_id)
    "email_address_idx" UNIQUE, btree (email_address)
Referenced by:
    TABLE "xref__email_addresses__organizations" CONSTRAINT "email_address_id_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (email_address_id) REFERENCES email_addresses(email_address_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE RESTRICT
```

Note they both have an `email_address_id` column and
`"email_address_id_idx" UNIQUE, btree (email_address_id)` index.

I need to drop the `email_address_id_idx` on the `xref__email_addresses__organizations` table but it seems if mis-created the table by having two identical index names.

How do I drop the `email_address_id_idx` from the `xref__email_addresses__organizations` table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what i have understood, the indexes are different. One of them is **email_address_id_idx** and the other is **email_address_idx**. So I Think you can just use ***drop index*** to remove the desired one.

Comment: Right, there cannot be two indexes with the same name in the same schema.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe There is an interesting edge case. You can have two indexes with the same name in different schemas, in which case `DROP INDEX <name>` yields a I`index <name>  does not exist, skipping` error. In this case, you have to specify the schema in the table name.